# "cannot unpack non-iterable function object" : trying to run a code through tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, mnist, dataloader

while running this code I am getting error

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data
```

this should run fine .

Anybody know how to resolve this?
Please help me

Comment: Use `mnist.load_data()` (with `()` at the end to call the function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `()` are missing in `load_data`. So,

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data
```

Should instead be:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```